# Python code for basic fft of grid image

Tags: python, fft

I'm trying to take an fft of an image in python, alter the transformed image and take a reverse fft. Specifically, I have a picture of a grid that I'd like to transform, then black out all but a central, narrow vertical slit of the transform, then take a reverse fft.

The code I'm working with now, for no alteration to transform plane:

```
import os
os.chdir('/Users/terra/Desktop')
import Image, numpy
i = Image.open('grid.png')
i = i.convert('L')    #convert to grayscale
a = numpy.asarray(i)  # a is readonly

b = abs(numpy.fft.rfft2(a))

j = Image.fromarray(b)
j.save('grid2.png')
```

As of now, I'm getting an error message:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/terra/Documents/pic2.py", line 11, in 
    j.save('grid2.png')
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/PIL/Image.py", line 1439, in save
    save_handler(self, fp, filename)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/PIL/PngImagePlugin.py", line 506, in _save
    raise IOError, "cannot write mode %s as PNG" % mode
IOError: cannot write mode F as PNG

I'm very new to programming and Fourier transforms, so most related threads I've found online are over my head. Very specific help is greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: In Python 2.5 I am getting no such error message for this code.

Comment: Stylistic, but I recommend you don't use the variable names `i` and `j` for anything but integer indexing variables, such as for going through a range or for loop.

Comment: Could you copy and paste your code into the console and then edit your question to include the entire resulting traceback?  (The only way I can think of offhand to trigger that error message would be if the code were really `a = numpy.asarray('i')` or something, but I'm not sure which line is the fourth.)

Answer (score 1):

The main problem is that the array contains floats after the FFT, but for it to be useful for PNG output, you need to have `uint8`s.

The simplest thing is to convert it to `uint8` directly:

```
b = abs(numpy.fft.rfft2(a)).astype(numpy.uint8)
```

This probably will not produce the image you want, so you'll have to normalize the values in the array somehow before converting them to integers.